Pulsar auto delete policy
I changed the configuration in pulsar's configuration file broker.conf to
brokerDeleteInactiveTopicsEnabled: true
brokerDeleteInactiveTopicsMode: delete_when_no_subscriptions
brokerDeleteInactiveTopicsMaxInactiveDurationSeconds: 120

Then I restarted pulsar's docker container and sent a message to the topic persistent://t_test/proj_test/web_hook_test, but when time passed, the topic was not removed and the admin rest API could query the topic information.

This topic does not have subscribers and the data returned by queries through the interface "/admin/v2/persistent/t_test/proj_test/web_hook_test/subscriptions" is empty

I want to clean up inactive topics with pulsar's auto-delete policy

First, the topic must be created dynamically. Not by pulsar-admin api.
Second, make sure you also set the
allowAutoTopicCreation=true

Last thing make sure you use = in conf/broker instead of : .
Also try to use newest pulsar version
